# Why do I have to use $timeout to update variables in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-timeout

I have a directive in a directive. In the deepest directive I have this:

directive B:

```
scope.onChange = function () {
    scope.ngModel = scope.selectedItem.Id;

    $timeout(function () {
        scope.changed();
    }, 0);
}
```

In the directive on top of that directive I have this:

Directive A:

```
scope.onChange = function () {
    console.log(scope.ngModel);

    scope.changed();
}
```

The thing is, when I omit the `timeout` call in directive B, the console logs the 'old' value, but when I use the `timeout` call, everything works as expected. So my question is, why do I need to use the `timeout`  here?

Comment: Sounds like the digest cycle has not run completely. Consider usage of a watcher and a shared service

Comment: Please post your code in Plunker or Fidddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is $timeout needed when dynamically nesting ng-form in Angular to ensure child form links with parent form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948066/why-is-timeout-needed-when-dynamically-nesting-ng-form-in-angular-to-ensure-chi)